# Scala - using string interpolation inside Trait containing unimplemented variable

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

Say I have the following Trait

```
trait Feature{
     val name:String
     val tableName = s"${name}_table"
}
```

and a class that extends it

```
class Feature1 extends Feature{
     val name = "feature1"
}
```

but when I initialize the class and print `tableName` I get "null_table" rather than "feature1_table".  I am trying to fully understand why that is.  Is it because since `tableName` is technically implemented within the Trait it takes the null value of `name` before it can get instantiated by the extending class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"is technically implemented within the Trait it takes the null value of name before it can get instantiated by the extending class"* Yes.

This is the workaround.

```
trait Feature {
  def name: String
  final lazy val tableName = s"${name}_table"
}

final class Feature1 extends Feature {
  override final val name = "feature1"
}
```

---

Another alternative would be using a `abstrac class` instead of a `trait`.
**Scala 3** will introduce trait parameters to properly fix this.

Comment: Note that `lazy val` is implemented with synchronization, which has a performance penalty. I recommend using `def` if the operation is cheap in a high performance multithreaded enviroment